# Get Date Range From MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get the date range like month and year of the data from MySQL database? For example if a table in database has the record of data from Feb 2012 to Jan 2013, how can I get to know the date range of stored data record?

Comment: Aggregate `MIN()` and `MAX()`.  How is your date column stored? Is it a proper `DATE / DATETIME` type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410642/mysql-datetime-diff-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the query

`select min(date_column), max(date_column) from your_table`