# How to calculate time difference in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with column 'start', which contain the start date of some tasks

```
+----------+---------------------+------------+
| name     | start               | end        |
+----------+---------------------+------------+
| p1       | 2014-12-08 15:56:03 |            | 
| p2       | 2014-12-08 15:56:03 |            | 
| p3       | 2014-12-08 15:56:03 |            | 
| ...      | ...                 | ...        | 
+----------+---------------------+------------+
```

I need to select, from this table all the tasks started for more than 48h
I tried

```
start between DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) and  NOW()
```

I googled and tried several ways to compare date but unfortunately didn't get the result as expected.

Comment: This seems to cover the issue purely in MySQL, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410642/mysql-datetime-diff-query.

Comment: Your query returns everything started within the last 48 hours. You just want `start < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)`

Comment: The statement "all the tasks started for more than 48h" doesn't make sense.  That is why sample data and desired results are so effective in questions for clarifying what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fluent on the ways of doing this purely with mysql, but you could do the dates with PHP (since you tagged this as using PHP too):

```
$startDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("-48 hours"));
$nowDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "select * from table where start >= '".$startDate."' AND start <= '".$nowDate."'";
// execute your sql statement here and fetch results
```

Comment: thank you for answer, actually i'm using the the statement under php
and it's work great, and as Tibor B. mentioned in his answer. to get just tasks older than 2 days i used
$sql = "select * from table where start <= '".$startDate."

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct MySQL statement for the results you'd like to achieve. Simply replace the word `table` with your MySQL table's name.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE start BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Edit: I've just noticed, that you are actually looking for every date, which is older than 2 days, rather than "within 2 days". So the MySQL statement for that is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE start < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the second statement is exactly what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be closest to what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE start BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE();
```